# How to start contributing to the Mojito repository on Github ? (javascript)

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, yahoo, mojito

How to study the code, understand, debug ? I know javascript but do not know where exactly to start. And I know how to use Github, Of course I know what Mojito is ! The problem is I donot know how to contribute to the Mojito. But i was very interested in it. Help me with some tips on where to start with Mojito contribution.
Note :: I was not asking about how to design apps for Mojito but asking how to develop Mojito Flatform

Answer (score 0):

You can fork the repo and work on it yourself, look at issues and work on fixes and commit to main repo or just clone it and use it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the contribute wiki:

https://github.com/yahoo/mojito/wiki/Contributing-Code-to-Mojito

Just follow the steps.